# element not visible: Element is not currently visible and may not be manipulated

Tags: java, selenium, selenium-webdriver

I'm trying to select one of the element from dropdown.I have retrieved 12 elements when I used the method `getAttribute()`:

```
    Select select = new Select(driver.findElement(By.xpath("//select[@id='dataset_downloadDataset_select']")));
    List<WebElement> options = select.getOptions();
    System.out.println(options.size());
    for (int i=1; i<=11; i++){
    System.out.println(options.get(i).getAttribute("value"));
```

After retrieving 12 elements of dropdowm,I want to select one of them.For that I have tried `Actions`/`Javascriptexecutor` but I'm getting element not visible exception.The code used for `Action` method is:

```
    WebElement mnuElement;
    WebElement submnuElement;

    mnuElement = driver.findElement(By.xpath("//input[starts-with(@data-activates,'sele')][@value='XXXXXXXXXXX']"));
    submnuElement = driver.findElement(By.xpath("//*[@id='dataset_downloadDataset_select']/option[4]"));
    Actions builder = new Actions(driver);
    builder.moveToElement(mnuElement).perform();
    Thread.sleep(5000);
    driver.findElement(By.xpath("//*[@id='dataset_downloadDataset_select']/option[4]")).click();
```

Could anyone help me to resolve this.

Comment: It is possible that it takes some time for the dropdown to be populated. Have you tried increasing Selenium's time out to find an element?

Comment: Yes,I have tried increasing that

Comment: @vijay_m, `builder.moveToElement(mnuElement).perform();` doesn't mean to open drop-down menu, so you cannot handle it's options. Try to click on `mnuElement` before clicking `submnuElement`

Comment: As suggested, I have tried to click the mnuelement before subelement but still element not visible exception.

Answer (score 0):

It depends on browser you are using. Chrome can click option without extending while firefox can't deal with it. Use select to choose from . Option you are using requires to click on the list and then choose, but it is simplier to do like that

Code for firefox (and probably every browser)

```
WebDriver driver;//then choosing browser
element=driver.findElement(By.xpath("//select[@id='dataset_downloadDataset_select']"));//or whatever
Select select=new Select(element);

//To select what you want, this is selecting, nothing more

select.selectByValue("Mainframe File 1");//or other
```

Comment: I'm using Chrome browser.I have tried by using select.selectByValue("value retrieved from getattribute"), I'm getting exeception 'element not found'.

Comment: can you send html of that element? (Inspect it and expand what is there)

Comment: <select id="dataset_downloadDataset_select" required="required" aria-required="true" data-ng-model="downloadDatasetInput.dataset" material-select="" watch="" class="initialized ng-pristine ng-untouched ng-valid ng-not-empty ng-valid-required" aria-invalid="false">

Comment: <select id="dataset_downloadDataset_select" required="required" aria-required="true" data-ng-model="downloadDatasetInput.dataset" material-select="" watch="" class="initialized ng-pristine ng-untouched ng-valid ng-not-empty ng-valid-required" aria-invalid="false"> <option ng-repeat="dataset in mainframeDatasets" value="Mainframe File 1" class="ng-binding ng-scope">Mainframe File 1</option><!-- end ngRepeat: dataset in mainframeDatasets -->

Comment: Do you choose the value or is this calculated in some way? If you are choosing it there is no point in creating whole list and then choosing. The simplest way if you are choosing is choosing directly "Mainframe File 1". Either you can choose by visible text. Gonna edit my code to minimal form that worked for all the dropdowns I have been using

Comment: If you code depends on some decision then I can make "extended" version, but if you are making the choice it is the simplest way

Comment: I have retrieved this value in for (int i=1; i<=11; i++){
System.out.println(options.get(i).getAttribute("value")).But when I use Select select = new Select(driver.findElement(By.xpath("//select[@id='dataset_downloadDataset_select']")));
  select.selectByVisibleText("Mainframe File-2");its throwing element not found exception